# How do you 'cleanse the pallet'?

Tags: moving, on, tricks, techniques, mental-health

Hello all,

So I'm just finishing up the last of a children's series, and getting ready to move on to a cool little indie feature. My question is this:

What tricks/techniques do you use to clear your mind of one project and get it ready for the next?

I like taking a little time off (esp. to catch up on missed sleep!) and watching/listening to media that's as far away from the previous project as I can, but I'd be curious in tapping the "Team Rocket" (thanks G.A!) braintrust to find other things that might apply.

Answer (score 3):

Hey Sonesy

If you are working in Ottawa I think your answer is across the river in Gatineau Park.  Hit the trails, rent a canoe, chill out in the quiet nature.  I worked in Ottawa for a while and loved to go snow shoeing in Gatineau to get rid of the stress of the job.  Wrong time of year for that but you get the idea.

I find the best way to cleanse the pallet is to not look at a screen of any kind for a couple days.  No TV, no internet, just let the brain unwind, either relaxing with a cold beverage in your hand or hiking/physical activity to whip up a sweat. The change really works wonders for me and I come back to the studio with a new perspective and reinvigorated with creativity.  There are only so many weeks a human can sit in a chair for 10 hours a day in the dark.....

Comment: One of my FAVOURITE get aways is to do a solo overnight camp in Gatineau Park - sadly not in the cards for the break I have coming. And how do you only get away with 10 hour days? :)

Answer (score 1):

Get out and spend time outdoors like the other rocket team members so aptly described.

After the cast/crew wrap-up party I like to:

Snowboard.
Surf.
Play basketball (that's me slam dunking in my profile photo).
Run/Hike/Explore.

I personally enjoy visiting my parent's house in Sacramento or going to Napa Valley or San Francisco (we have to meet up sometime, NoiseJockey!!!)

Depending on how much time you allow yourself, unfortunately sometimes it's just an evening before you're back in the thick of it, it can vary from taking a walk around the block to going on a full-on vacation. I thoroughly enjoy the latter.

;)

Comment: Family in Sacramento are?  Hah, small world.

Comment: @Stavrosound Was just up there from Jan 1st to the 7th. You have family there, too?

Answer (score 0):

(Doffs hat + blush)

Lately I've been finding it harder and harder to clean out my head. So much film and music assumes a really low common denominator and consequently leaves almost nothing to the imagination. Every moment of every scene is stuffed to the gills with some kind of ADD satisfying sting or lense flare. The camera shakes, the low-end quakes, and my head begins to ache.

So I've been gravitating more towards music and film designed to provide a basis, and foundational texture that let's my imagination do a bit more work. Check out some Gavin Bryars, especially Jesus' Blood Never Failed Me Yet. It's really slow and quiet; great for an hour of chillout. Autechre is pretty magical for that too.

Then of course there's the old standby of Music for Aiports by Brian Eno. That'll clean you up good and proper. Especially coming off a kids show, which tend to be totally frenetic and overstimulating.

For movies try Solaris, or Snow Angels. I watch a lot of documentaries too, they tend to give you a little more brain space.

But maybe you just need a good ol' walk in the park.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to clear your mind of one project and get ready for the next. One thing that seems to connect all of what most people are suggesting is that you are away from a computer screen! Here are some of the things I do in-between projects:

- Definitely get out and about if you can. Doesn't have to be far, just away from your usual surroundings.
- Doing sport can be a great way to re-energise the creativity.
- So too can being around nature.
- I also love to read a good book.
- Go and see a play or an exhibition.

Whatever floats your boat really. We can draw influence from many different creative fields.